# flexbox - how to make 2 flex-item have same width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I want 2 flex-item have the same width, no matter what is the width of the content.

After I set `flex: 1 1 0;` on flex-item, it still not works as expected
because I expect the width of `ME` will be same as `Everyone`

[image]

App.js

```
import React from 'react'

import "./style.css";

function Tab() {
    return (
        <div className="tab">   
            <div className="tab__item">Me</div>
            <div className="tab__item">Everyone</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tab
```

style.css

```
.tab {
  display: flex;
}
.tab .tab__item {
  flex: 1 1 0; // not working
  border: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
}
```

Comment: `flex:1 1 0` stands for: `flex-grow` `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`  set to **0** , use auto instead so it can expand .

Comment: @CCCC Your example code works fine in isolation, so I'd suspect a problem elsewhere. If you inspect the elements in your actual site, do you see the styles properly applied? Here's an example of your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/bdste4r5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It might be related to your other styles somewhere else but you could try this**

```js
    function App() {
    return (
        <div className="tab">   
            <div className="tab__item">Me</div>
            <div className="tab__item">Everyone</div>
        </div>
    )
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
}
.tab .tab__item {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: turn out it works after I add `width: 100%` on container and item.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```
.tab .tab__item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
}
```